# Calling constructor from shared method (C# to VB.Net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, constructor

I have not enough experience in VB.NET, I have a Windows Forms VB.NET application and I'm trying to do what in C# I'd do in this way:

```
public class MyForm{    
    MyForm(string caption) {
        _caption = caption;
        if(...){
            BaseForm.Show(caption);
      }
    }

    public static void Show(string caption) {
        new MyForm(caption);
    }
}
```

(BaseForm is another class I have in the application with a static method Show). All works fine in C#, but in Visual Basic .NET I'm not able to call the constructor.
The constructor has become:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal caption As String)
        _caption = caption
        If ...
            BaseForm.Show(caption)
        End If
End Sub
```

But what is the VB.NET equivalent for `new classname(parameters)`? What i've tried:

```
Public Shared Sub Show(ByVal caption As String)
    MyForm.New(caption)
End Sub 

Public Shared Sub Show(ByVal caption As String)
    Me.New(caption)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Show(ByVal caption As String)
    New MyForm(caption)
End Sub
```

None of these works. It also appears that online C#-VB.NET converters give me the third option as answer (I wouldn't have tried that) but it's wrong. VS 2017 gives me the following errors respectively:

1. "Constructor call is valid only as the first statement in an
   instance constructor"
2. This obviously doesn't work because a shared/static method can't call an instance
3. "Syntax error"

EDIT: Sorry for the mistake, I originally posted a code where I was passing three arguments in the VB.NET functions. However, in my real code the functions have more arguments and I'm sure this is not the problem. I thought it would have been clearer if I had only shown you the essential code since the complete code is too long but forgot to delete the additional arguments in some functions

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(MyForm), New Object() {text, caption, timeout})`

Comment: Or `New String() {caption}` etc.

Comment: Last version of the function is correct syntax, but you are passing too much parameters than constructor if MyForm accepts. Constructor declared to accepts only one parameter, but in the function you gave three.

Comment: As @Fabio, you've basically already got the answer. Look at the C# code you're trying to convert: `new MyForm(caption);`. It should be obvious that you simply remove the semicolon and you have your VB code? Why would C# code with one argument translate to VB code with three. The solution is simply `New MyForm(caption)`.

Comment: You have managed to make your question more confusing by apparently putting the `BaseForm.Show` method inside the `MyForm` class. My first thought was that you had not shown us the code that you were having trouble converting but then I realised that you had. Please make your questions clearer in future. It's fairly good apart from that one glaring fault.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: That's what makes VB so, um, interesting.  You can't just use "New MyForm(caption)" - you need to assign it to something.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, I was assuming that the C# code provided was just for example, e.g. the `Show` method is stated to be a member of `BaseForm` but shown to be a member of `MyForm`. If the original `Show` method really is a shown above then there are greater issues than converting it, given that it is completely useless code. Why it exists in the first place is a more important question than how to convert it.

Comment: @Fabio the number of arguments is not the problem, see my edit note

Comment: @jmcilhinney the number of arguments is not the problem and yes, the code has been cut to be simpler. The purpose of the code is that the Show method of this "customized" form actually shows always the same form, but sets some parameters. However it works in C#, the issue is that in Visual Basic I have to assign a temporary variable or use "with" as others have said.

Comment: Side note... why is the _constructor_ of a form showing another form? Seems like that should be in the 'load' or 'shown' event instead. Or is `MyForm` not actually a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential issue here is that VB does not allow "naked" expressions to be statements. C# (and Java) restricts expressions as statements to the following:

- Assignment expressions
- Any use of ++ or --
- Method invocations
- Object creation expressions

Regarding the first two points, VB has sort-of equivalents. VB doesn't have a built-in assignment expression; instead it has an assignment statement. VB doesn't have `++` or `--` operators; it only has `+=` and `-=` assignment statements. In any case, via helper Functions one can make fully emulated equivalents of them in VB.

Of the above points, only the "Method invocations" one is allowed in VB. The "Object creation expressions" is not.

So something like `New MyForm()` is an expression, despite the pretense of `Sub New()`. The most straight-forward work-around is to make use of local variables (as others have already suggested):

```
Dim tmp As New MyForm(Text, caption, timeout)
```

Another idea is using `With`:

```
With New MyForm(Text, caption, timeout) : End With
```

If you figure this is the sort of thing you'll be doing a lot, maybe you could add a private or protected method to your class that does nothing:

```
    Private Sub NoOp()
    End Sub
```

and use it like so:

```
Call New MyForm(Text, caption, timeout).NoOp()
```

That works because the `Call` statement allows for expressions on the way towards getting at a method invocation.

Alternatively, you could make a helper function in a `Module` like so:

```
#Disable Warning IDE0060 ' Remove unused parameter
    Friend Sub [Call](Of T)(x As T)
#Enable Warning IDE0060 ' Remove unused parameter
    End Sub
```

And then do this with it:

```
[Call](New MyForm(Text, caption, timeout)) ' Note square brackets on [Call]
```

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET, you should use a temporary variable:

```
Dim tempVar As New MyForm(caption)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyForm` constructor takes only one parameter and your `Show` method is wrong and should be like this to return the newly created instance.

```
Public Shared Function Show(ByVal caption As String) As MyForm
    Return New MyForm(caption)
End Function
```

The real issue here is your design, you should not have any logic implemented inside of your constructor.

Something like this instead

```
Public Sub Show()
    BaseForm.Show(_caption)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Show(ByVal caption As String)
    Dim form = New MyForm(caption)
    form.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of question there are many C# to VB converters, including at least 2 Free Open Source once that will do the conversion for you. One is mine at https://github.com/paul1956/CSharpToVB